# Trying to select certain characters from user input

Tags: python, typeerror

My goal here is to set `p` as the last two digits of `year` but when I run the program I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers` for the line `p = str(year)[2,3]`.

I've tried taking out `str` in `p = str(year)[2,3]` but then I get `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.

I'm not sure what I can do here.

```
year_original=int(input("Enter the 4-digit year: "))
month=int(input("Enter the month as a number: "))
day=int(input("Enter the day as a number: "))

if month == 1 or 2:
    year = year_original-1
p = str(year)[2,3]
q = str(year)[0,1]
r = ((month + 9)//12)+1
s = (13*r-1)/5
t = p/4
u = q/4
v = d+p+s+t+u+(5*q)
w=v//7
print(month,day,",",year_original,"is a ",w)
```

**EDIT**
Thanks to the answer I've figured out and solved the problem. I also completed the code.

```
year_original=int(input("Enter the 4-digit year: "))
month=int(input("Enter the month as a number: "))
day=int(input("Enter the day as a number: "))

if month == 1 or 2:
    year = year_original-1
p = str(year)[2:3]
q = str(year)[0:1]
r = ((month + 9)%12)+1
s = (13*r-1)/5
t = int(p)/4
u = int(q)/4
v = int(day)+int(p)+int(s)+int(t)+int(u)+(5*int(q))
w=v%7

if w == 0:
    w = "Sunday"
elif w == 1:
    w = "Monday"
elif w == 2:
    w = "Tuesday"
elif w == 3:
    w = "Wendsday"
elif w == 4:
    w = "Thursday"
elif w == 5:
    w = "Friday"
elif w == 6:
    w = "Saturday"

if month == "1" or "01":
    month = "January"
elif month == "2" or "02":
    month = "Febuary"
elif month == "3" or "03":
    month = "March"
elif month == "4" or "04":
    month = "April"
elif month == "5" or "05":
    month = "May"
elif month == "6" or "06":
    month = "June"
elif month == "7" or "07":
    month = "July"
elif month == "8" or "08":
    month = "August"
elif month == "9" or "09":
    month = "September"
elif month == "10":
    month = "October"
elif month == "11":
    month = "November"
elif month == "12":
    month = "December"

print(month,day,",",year_original,"is a ",w)
```

Comment: Would `str(year)[2:]` do?

Comment: Any reason - if you're going to ask for a four digit year and ignore the century, why not just ask for a two digit year to start with? And while I think I've got a guess at what you're trying to do here, the single letter variables names don't help - what are you trying to do here?

Comment: @JonClements the program calculates what day of the week a given numerical date is. I do actually need the century as it is used by the line `q = str(year)[0:1]`. The reason I'm using single letter variables is because they are just place holders in the calculation. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: @CaptainNewfoundland it does - is this an exercise you're doing then? Python has some reasonable good type datetime handling you can get a from string

Comment: Look at `datetime.strptime` - that's already done it all for you (not to mention your logic isn't doing what you think it is)

Comment: @JonClements thanks for letting me know about `datetime.strptime`. What is wrong with my logic?

Comment: @CaptainNewfoundland look at it when you have time and it can process your string into a datetime object and you can then easily ask it what day of the week it is :) Just ask your date as a single string in some format (or concatenate those) and run stptime...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ',' creates a tuple, so `year[2,3]` is the same as `year[(2,3)]` which isn't supported in python. Instead write `year[2:4]` (and `year[0,1]` to `year[0:2]`)